# Test videoRef.current?.play chaining function with react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I have the following component, it works as expected, but I am having problems testing the line `console.log("there was an error playing the video");` but I am not able to mock it

```tsx
import PlayArrowIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PlayArrow";
import { get } from "lodash";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

const VideoPlayer = () => {
  const [showPlayButton, setShowPlayButton] = useState(true);
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  const togglePlay = () => {
    setShowPlayButton((current) => {
      if (current === true) {
        const playAction = get(videoRef, "current.play", () => {
          console.log("there was an error playing the video");
        });
        playAction();
      }
      return false;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={togglePlay} data-testid="player-container">
      {showPlayButton && (
        <button aria-label="Player button" data-testid="player-button">
          <PlayArrowIcon sx={{ fontSize: "2rem" }} />
        </button>
      )}
      <video
        ref={videoRef}
        data-cy="player-video"
        className="player-video"
        data-testid="player-video"
        controls={!showPlayButton}
        style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
        src={"https://google.com/video-file.mp4"}
        poster={"https://google.com/video-image.jpg"}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

This is the current test code, I have been trying to make `videoRef.current` to not exist

```ts
import { fireEvent, render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import VideoPlayer from "../components/video-player";

describe("VideoPlayer Component", () => {
  let playStub: jest.SpyInstance<Promise<void>, [], any>;
  let consoleSpy: jest.SpyInstance;

  beforeEach(() => {
    playStub = jest.spyOn(window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype, "play");
    consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, "log").mockImplementation(() => {});
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    playStub.mockRestore();
    consoleSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it("clicking video should make it play and hide arrow button", async () => {
    playStub.mockResolvedValue();

    const { getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(<VideoPlayer />);

    const playButtonStart = getByTestId("player-button");
    expect(playButtonStart).toBeInTheDocument();

    const videoPlayerStart = getByTestId("player-container");
    fireEvent.click(videoPlayerStart);

    await waitFor(() => expect(playStub).toHaveBeenCalled());

    const playButtonFinal = queryByTestId("player-button");
    expect(playButtonFinal).not.toBeInTheDocument();

    fireEvent.click(videoPlayerStart);
    expect(playStub).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

And this is the uncovered line

```sh
yarn test
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
$ cross-env BABEL_ENV=test jest --coverage
 PASS  src/__tests__/video-player.test.tsx
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                 | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files            |   98.79 |      100 |   93.33 |   98.78 |                   
 src/components      |   98.07 |      100 |      90 |   98.03 |                   
  video-player.tsx   |   93.33 |      100 |      75 |   93.33 | 13                
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The lodash get method searches for the path passed as second parameter and returns the default value if the search results in `undefined`.

Therefore, to test the case for the default value `videoRef.current.play` must be forced to `undefined`:

```
it("clicking video should do nothing if video can not be played", () => {
    window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play = undefined;

    const { getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(<VideoPlayer />);

    const playButtonStart = getByTestId("player-button");
    expect(playButtonStart).toBeInTheDocument();

    const videoPlayerStart = getByTestId("player-container");
    fireEvent.click(videoPlayerStart);

    expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

**A couple of extra notes**

- When analyzing coverage it can be tempting to try and cover 100% of your code and lose sight of what we are really testing. What I mean by this is that testing is a good opportunity to question ourselves if the code we are testing makes real sense. When is `videoRef.current.play` going to be undefined? Are we really taking into account a real scenario?
- When testing, the focus should be put in the user. In case the video element does not provide the `play` method instead of logging to console a modal could be shown so that the user has feedback of what is going on. This way the test could check if a modal has been shown instead of checking if `console.log` has been called, which is irrelevant to the user.